# How to know the petalinux version?

Tags: linux, petalinux

I have my embedded linux tool running in my linux machine. How can i know its version? I don't know whether my petalinux tool is from 2016.4 or 2017.1!

Comment: How do *we* know the version of your embedded linux tool? Does the tool have a --version option? Or are you asking about the version *of* PetaLinux??

Comment: There is a file `.version-history`at the top level of the PetaLinux installation. So,  `cat $PETALINUX/.version-history` should print something like `PETALINUX_BASE_VER=2019.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to know the version of PetaLinux you were using.

But, if you can ssh to connect to your system, using the command `uname -a` will give you the kernel version, which will give you the according PetaLinux version. **This is only true is you did not change the kernel version yourself.**

According to the documentation :

- Kernel Version 4.6 -> PetaLinux 2016.4  (https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/68370.html)
- Kernel Version 4.9 -> PetaLinux 2017.1  (https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/69074.html)